# Syntax Error: Comma in Query Expression of SQL Statement?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Alright folks, I am 100% Batshit insane at this point. Can someone possibly help me here? I'm clueless after trying EVERYTHING and searching for others with this experience. I'm at a loss here. I've tried brackets around all the table/field names. I've tried taking the tablename off the Select fields, I've tried moving the parenthesis backwards and forwards but to no avail.

The error I get is: "Syntax Error (comma) in query expression. '( [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8] )'.

```
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [tblSalesJournal] ( [Store], [Business Unit], [Country], [State], [Store Type], [Net Sales], [Fee], [Total] ) " & _
    "SELECT ( [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8] ) " & _
    "FROM [tblImport]"
```

Any help is GREATLY appreciated

Answer (score 9):

The problem is:

```
SELECT ( [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8] )
```

You should not bracket a SELECT statement, therefore

```
SELECT [F1], [F2], [F3], [F4], [F5], [F6], [F7], [F8]
```

Some MS errors are odd.

Comment: INSERT INTO SET uses brackets
INSERT INTO VALUES uses brackets...

But INSERT INTO SELECT doesn't?!?!?!!? BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAH!!!!! ARRRRRRRRRGH!!!

Thanks bud, I'll proceed to pull my head out of the wall now.

Comment: There is a lot to be said for building your query in MS Access query design window, so you get the MS Access syntax right. You can also create your query string -- DIM sSQL As String; sSQL= "SELECT etc"', which will allow you to DEBUG.PRINT sSQL and paste it into the SQL view of the query design window.

Comment: Actually, user2296381, you really only need brackets ("[" and "]") if there is a space in your field name, and that's just so the code knows it's a single "word".  If you name all your tables and fields with no spaces (use underscores if absolutely necessary), you'll never need brackets.  You're probably confused with parenthesis ("(" and ")") which you never use in a **SELECT** statement.

Comment: @Jonnybones Good point. Or if you have reserved words. I would generally recommend prefixing a field / column name with a table alias to avoid all problems of this nature and to help with future database changes.

Comment: @user2296381 - there's no such thing as '`insert into set`'. `insert into table (...) values (...)` uses parens because you're building literal rows to insert into the table. The parens delimit the literal rows. `insert into table (...) select ...` doesn't use parens because you're 'selecting' the rows to insert from somewhere--not building them up on the spot.